# Date calculation subtracting date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field with sales_start_date( values like 2014-06-17 ,2015-07-23...)
I need to do calculation based on sales_start date..

I have to take the most recent month-end date(i have to force this value to 2016-07-31) and subtract the sale_start_date to get an integer count of the days elapsed. If number of days passed is less than 2 default the value 2

sales_start_date

```
2016-01-01
2016-07-30
```

Output

```
Calculated field
155
2
```

Can any one help me in writing case statement.
Your help is much appreciated.

Thank You,
Swathi.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Show your attempt(s) at solving the problem and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: i know how to write the case statement and know how to do minus 30 days or 2months like that by using  DATEADD(DAY, –30, COLUMNAME).but not sure how to subtract to get an integer ocunt of the days. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Again - show the query you have, and point out where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day,<enter start date column here>,<most recent month-end date column here>) AS [Calculated field]
FROM <your table here>
```

Comment: Thank You So much.. It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

SQL-server 2012 + you have the EOMONTH() to help you get to the end of the month more easily.

```
;WITH cteData AS (
    SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) as Start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-07-30'
)

SELECT
    EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) as EndOfPreviousMonth
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,Start_date,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))) + 1 as DaysDifferent
FROM
    cteData
```